# Internet explorer hanging with long running AJAX WebMethod on SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a couple of SetTimeouts for when the page loads which will load in chart data using AJAX calls to the code behind.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setTimeout(drawGraphs, 0);
        window.setTimeout(drawGraphsCharts, 0);
    });
```

This works great in Chrome and Firefox, however if one of the methods takes a long time, e.g. 1-5 seconds to finish, Internet Explorer hangs when this is taking place until this has completed, rather than loading one by one like the other browsers.

Has anyone come across this and how to fix it.

I am simulating a long running method at the moment using the following in my web method.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        var test = i + i;
        var test2 = i * i;
    }
```

Comment: there's a big difference between thrashing your CPU with a synchronous loop like that and an AJAX call (you know what the first A in AJAX stands for?) - what your "simulation" shows you is that internet explorer is slow at maths

Comment: Internet explorer hangs when there is long running javascript methods. Try to split your work.

Comment: In internet explorer it doesn't show either graphs until they have both finished, whereas chrome and firefox show the first chart and then the second 2 seconds later when the calculation has finished.  In my example only one of the webmethods has this calculation running.

Comment: I am splitting as much as possible, however I am trying to simulate a long database call rather than just in JavaScript.